# Select top 1 from each group entity frameworks

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity

I am trying to group a list of devices with mac addresses.  I have tried this in linqpad and it works successfully.  However when I try and run this in Entity frameworks I get an error saying "Specified method is not supported."

Here is my code:

```
var db = new centraliteEntitiews();

var network = from n in db.infoes
              where (n.state != 2) || (n.nodeid != 0)
              orderby n.time
              group n by n.mac into g
              select g.FirstOrDefault();
return View(network);
```

I would like it to return a list of object to send to my view.

MacAddress  state  nodeid  uptime etc

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
var network = db.infoes
  .Where(n => (n.state != 2) || (n.nodeid != 0))
  .GroupBy(n => n.mac)
  .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(n => n.time).First()) // sort within groups instead of all inputs, select info ungrouped (1 from each)
  .ToList() // to memory
  .SortBy(n => n.time) // sort results (between groups)
  .ToList(); // to memory
```

Comment: Sorry for the different syntax - I am a bit more fluent in LINQ extension methods than in LINQ query expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's `FirstOrDefault()` that's not supported, you could try just changing it to `First()`. After all, you *know* there's at least one element in each group, as otherwise the group wouldn't exist.

Comment: When I try First() I get the following error.  The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.

Comment: @Jonathan: Hmm. Odd. *Is* it `FirstOrDefault()` that's causing the error in your original post? (You didn't say.)